# Scanner on textfile fails to add elements to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm quite new to Java and have tried to scan a .txt file to retrieve individual words from it.

Where did I get it wrong, because no element is added to the ArrayList?

```
public class ScanInputFile {

public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void importArrayList(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File textFile = new File(path);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(textFile);
    while (s.hasNext()){
        list.add(s.next());
    }
    s.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    importArrayList("C:\\MyFirstList.txt");
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
}
```

}

This throws an IndexOutOfBounds Exception even though the txt file contains 10 words with 2 words per line.

Having had problems with FileNotFoundExceptions, I made sure that path.exists() and path.canRead() come back true.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you debugged whether `hasNext()` is `true` at least once?

Comment: show complete error

Comment: Yes I did. Up to replacing the txt file as written below, it never returned true.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with the Code you posted, it worked out for me - what does your file look like? I tried with:

boo
foo
roo
zoo

Console printed: "boo".

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response as well. I created a new document containing your example list and all of a sudden it worked... must have been something with my .txt file... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You code is executing fine for me. The 'list' is also populated as per expected also. Only change I have made is that file path. You have put directly under C:/ and I put it under a folder. But that shouldn't be a prob. If you put the last S.O.P statement under a loop it would print all. But I am not getting as such IndexOutOfBoundExpection

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I put the file there for purpose of example only as the directory tree was quite deep.
I have no clue what fixed it, but clearing my old list and creating a new .txt. solved the problem.